# Populate a table from a list using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I need to populate a table using 2 criteria to match the information.
the source data is

```
      A            B      C
    Month       Segment Value
    01/08/18    Alfa    236.200
    01/08/18    Bravo   39.700
    01/09/18    Alfa    8.400
    01/09/18    Delta   48.200
    01/10/18    Bravo   31.700
    01/11/18    Foxtrot 53.200
    01/11/18    Foxtrot 35.100...
```

And the table is

```
          G           H           I
      01/08/18    01/09/18    01/10/18...
Alfa            
Bravo                   
Delta
```

I have an idea to use Index and Match but i cant make it work.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a pivot table with your source data.

- Column Labels = Segment
- Row Labels = Month
- Values = Value

Your values can be aggregated by count, sum, average, etc.

Comment: thanks but i cant use pivot tables (is part of the requirement)

Comment: @rzb1 Is this homework?